# Comparing an array of strings

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am working on a deck of cards. My hands are an array of strings. For example:

```
hand1 = ["10 of ♣", "5 of ♣", "5 of ♠", "A of ♦", "3 of ♦"]
```

I want to evaluate and compare the hands. How can I identify and compare this object? My example has a pair but if I do something like

```
hand1.select{ |value| hand1.count(value) > 1 }
```

this returns an empty array. If I do

```
hand1.detect{ |value| hand1.count(value) > 1 }
```

it returns `nil` because both parts are not the same.

It works if I use a hand like

```
hand1 = ["10 of ♣", "10 of ♣", "J of ♠", "A of ♦", "3 of ♦"]
```

but having a suited pair is a problem for my program.

Comment: If I were you, I'll create a custom type for cards, instead of using strings like `"10 of ♣"`

Comment: Agree with @YuHao above. You should create an Object for each card.

Comment: The question is not clear. What do you want to identify? Which object do you want to compare with which object? What is the result that you want?

Comment: The cards are a class, I was saving them to a string because it has been easier, up to this point.  My deck class creates the deck so that I do not have duplicates. So, How can I compare the objects then? @YuHao

Comment: @sawa I want to be able to identiy that the hand has a pair (or what the hand is based on a random draw) and compare it to another to determine a winner.  I am a bit new here, so I apologize for the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 4):

#### Direct answer

Perform a regular expression check on the strings, to see whether the numbers are equal. Something like:

```
hand1 = ["10 of ♣", "5 of ♣", "5 of ♠", "A of ♦", "3 of ♦"]
hand1.select do |card|
  value = card[/^\w+/] # This will equal 10, 5, A or 3
  hand1.count { |other_card| other_card.match(value) } > 1
end
```

This will return an `Array` of all cards in the hand, for which there is a matching value card in the hand. I'm unclear whether that's exactly the data you want, but you get the idea.

#### Better answer

Don't do this. Doing everything in `String`s is *not* simpler; your code will end up much more confusing to read/write/test/debug.

Use the original `card` objects instead, and define suitable methods on the `Card` class (or whatever you've called it). For example, the implementation could be something like:

```
class Card
  attr_reader :value, :suit
  def initialize(value, suit)
     @value = value
     @suit = suit
  end

  # I'm not actually using these two methods here, but read
  # them for inspiration!...
  def to_s
    "#{value} of #{suit}"
  end

  def ==(other)
    value == other.value && suit == other.suit
  end
end

hand1 = [Card.new('10', '♣'), ....]

hand1.select do |card|
  hand1.count { |other_card| card.value == other_card.value) } > 1
end
```

#### Even better answer:

Let's take this one step further. Rather than defining an `Array` of cards, and then a bunch of global methods on that `Array`, why not define a `Hand` class, which holds this list of `Card` objects?

Your end result, which is pretty easy to expand upon, would be an additional class like:

```
class Hand
  attr_accessor :cards
  def initialize(cards = [])
    @cards = cards
  end

  def matching_values
    cards.select do |card|
      cards.count { |other_card| card.value == other_card.value) } > 1
    end
  end
end
```

You can then just deal with `hand` objects, and call methods such as `hand.matching_values`. No more dubious arrays, strings, regexes and global methods. Object Oriented Programming at its finest :)

Comment: Thank you for all the help Tom, I am going with your even better answer.  So I am calling deck = Deck.new to generate the deck, deck.shuffle, hand1 = deck.draw in my winner class.  So I can move that to a Hand class, can I generate multiple hands?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. And in order to ensure that you don't have duplicate cards, just keep track of them all in the deck.

Answer (score 0):

As Yu mentioned above, you probably want to create a `Card` class. It's not clear from your question how you want to evaluate the hand, but here's how you can check for a pair:

```
def pair_for hand
  values = hand.map{|c| c.scan(/\w+/).first }
  values.detect{|v| values.count(v) == 2 }
end
```

This method does not handle the case for when there are two pair, or three of a kind.

This method returns `nil` if there is no pair, so that's not so good. However, if you evaluate a hand from highest value to lowest, then `nil` might be a good choice.

Comment: @B Seven will this return a true or false?  How do I ask IRB for it? Sorry, code noob here. I plan to make all the other hands as separate methods

Comment: @Laurie - It will return the value of a pair (5), if it exists. If not, it will return `nil`. To test, you can copy and paste into irb: `hand = ...` and the above method and `pair_for hand`.

Comment: @B Seven When I do that I get NoMethodError: undefined method `scan' for #<Card:0x007f835904a9c8 @suit="♣", @value="J">
 from (irb):29:in `block in pair_for'
 from (irb):29:in `map'
 from (irb):29:in `pair_for'
 from (irb):32

Comment: I see you have created the `Card` class, but it is not in your question. I wrote the answer for card strings.

Comment: @B Seven , I had my card class concluding with a to string.  I took that out based on the above feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```
def rank(hand)
  cards = hand.map(&:split)
  ranks = cards.group_by(&:first)
  suits = cards.group_by(&:last)

  case 
  when ranks.one? { |k, v| v.count == 2 }
    "pair"
  when suits.count == 1
    "flush"
  end
end

player1 = rank ["10 of ♣", "5 of ♣", "5 of ♠", "A of ♦", "3 of ♦"]
=> "pair" 

player2 = rank ["10 of ♣", "4 of ♣", "5 of ♣", "A of ♣", "3 of ♣"]
=> "flush"
```

I did the easy ones and there is a lot of logic to go. You are certainly better off working with your class as others have stated.

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong about some of the rules concerning the determination of the winning hand in five-card poker (draw? stud? other?), but the code below can be easily modified to correct any errors in my assumptions.

The "kicker" is the tie-breaker. For example, if two hands both contain straights, the "kicker" is the card with the highest rank (for 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7, 7 is the "kicker"). If both hands have the same kicker, it's a tie. For a hand with, say, two 5's and two queens, the first kicker is the higher of the ranks (the queen), and if that rank is the same for another hand with two pairs, `5` becomes the kicker. If both hands have pairs of queens and a pair of 5's, it's a tie. Note the possibility of multiple "winners".

Hands are compared by associated arrays, which I've called "hand values". The first element of the array is a non-negative integer representing the type of hand, with `0` denoting "high card" (all cards have different ranks and not all suits are the same), `1` denoting one pair, and so on, up to `8` for a straight-flush. The second element of the array is the kicker (if there is one) and in one case (two pair) there is a third element that is the second kicker, should the first one not decide the winner. Arrays are ordered lexicographically in Ruby (see [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)), so we can determine the winner (or winners in the case of a tie) by finding which array is greatest.

I've assumed a hand is represented like so:

```
[['J', :clubs], ['2', :spades], ['J', :diamonds], ['2', :hearts], ['J', :spades]]
```

This may entail a conversion from some other format (that I've not discussed).

**Code**

```
RANK_STR_TO_RANK = %w| 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 J Q K A |.
  each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(s,i),h| h[s] = i }
  #=> {"2"=>0, "3"=>1, "4"=>2, "5"=>3, "6"=>4, "7"=>5,
  #    "8"=>6, "9"=>7, "J"=>8, "Q"=>9, "K"=>10, "A"=>11} 

HIGH_CARD       = 0
TWO_OF_KIND     = 1
TWO_PAIR        = 2
THREE_OF_KIND   = 3
STRAIGHT        = 4
FLUSH           = 5
FULL_HOUSE      = 6
FOUR_OF_KIND    = 7
STRAIGHT_FlUSH  = 8
```

```
def winners(hands)
  hands_and_values = hands.map { |hand| [hand, hand_value(hand)] }
  winning_value = hands_and_values.map(&:last).max
  hands_and_values.select { |_, value| value == winning_value }.map(&:first)
end 

def hand_value(hand)
  ranks, suits = convert(hand).transpose
  case
  when straight_flush?(ranks, suits)    then [STRAIGHT_FlUSH, ranks.max]
  when (kicker = four_of_kind?(ranks))  then [FOUR_OF_KIND, kicker]
  when (kicker = full_house?(ranks))    then [FULL_HOUSE, kicker]
  when flush?(suits)                    then [FLUSH]
  when straight?(ranks)                 then [STRAIGHT, ranks.max]
  when (kicker = three_of_kind?(ranks)) then [THREE_OF_KIND, kicker]
  when (kickers = two_pair?(ranks))     then [TWO_PAIR, *kickers]
  else                                       [HIGH_CARD, ranks.max]
  end
end
```

```
def convert(hand)
  hand.map { |rank_str, suit| [RANK_STR_TO_RANK[rank_str], suit] }
end

def straight_flush?(ranks, suits)
  straight?(ranks) && flush?(suits)
end

def four_of_kind?(ranks)
  h = group_by_rank(ranks)
  h.key?(4) ? h[4].first : false
end

def full_house?(ranks)
  h = group_by_rank(ranks)
  (h.key?(3) && h.key?(2)) ? h[3].first : false
end

def flush?(suits)
  suits.uniq.size == 1
end
```

```
def straight?(ranks)
  smallest, largest = ranks.minmax
  largest - smallest == 4 && ranks.uniq.size == 5 
end

def three_of_kind?(ranks)
  h = group_by_rank(ranks)
  h.key?(3) ? h[3].first : false
end

def two_pair?(ranks)
  h = group_by_rank(ranks)
  h.key?(2) && h[2].size==2 ? h[2].sort.reverse : false
end

def one_pair?(ranks)
  h = group_by_rank(ranks)
  h.key?(2) ? h[2].first : false
end

def group_by_rank(ranks)
  ranks.group_by(&:itself).each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h| (h[v.size] ||= []) << k }
end
```

**Example**

```
hands = [[['J', :clubs], ['2', :spades], ['J', :diamonds], ['2', :hearts], ['J', :spades]],
         [['Q', :hearts], ['3', :clubs], ['Q', :clubs], ['A', :hearts], ['3', :spades]],
         [['4', :hearts], ['5', :spades], ['6', :hearts], ['7', :hearts], ['8', :spades]],
         [['5', :clubs], ['9', :clubs], ['K', :clubs], ['A', :clubs], ['8', :clubs]]]

winners(hands)
  #=> [
  #    [["J", :clubs], ["2", :spades], ["J", :diamonds], ["2", :hearts], ["J", :spades]]
  #   ]
```

**Notes**

In `winners`, the intermediate values are as follows.

```
hands_and_values
  #=> [[[["J", :clubs], ["2", :spades], ["J", :diamonds], ["2", :hearts], ["J", :spades]],
  #      [6, 8]],
  #    [[["Q", :hearts], ["3", :clubs], ["Q", :clubs], ["A", :hearts], ["3", :spades]],
  #      [2, 9, 1]],
  #    [[["4", :hearts], ["5", :spades], ["6", :hearts], ["7", :hearts], ["8", :spades]],
  #      [4, 6]],
  #    [[["5", :clubs], ["9", :clubs], ["K", :clubs], ["A", :clubs], ["8", :clubs]],
  #      [5]]
  #   ]

winning_value
  #=> [6, 8]
```

The value of the first hand is `6, 8, 0`, which means that it is a `FULL_HOUSE` (`6`) with `3` jacks (`rank=>8`) and `2` `2's` (`rank=>0`). If two hands have full houses, the rank of the three-of-a-kind is the "kicker", or tie-breaker.